# Sync files to S3 with new Node App feature in cPanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cpanel

I run a Wordpress site and want to sync files uploaded by a customer to a specific folder in Wordpress to S3 automatically. I have been stuck trying to find a PHP or SSH solution on a limited cPanel account, until I saw the "Setup Node App" which seems to be a new feature in cPanel.

Can the *AWS SDK for JavaScript* package fulfill this sync role if installed within the same folder I want to sync to S3?

I have previously used the S3Cmd on an EC2 that appears to have a sync function, but no up to date NPM equivalent. Hence looking at the official AWS SDK.

Can an S3 sync be performed with a NodeJS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a NodeJS app that can handle S3 sync.

A possible flow for the function could be list all objects in the bucket, using [listObjectsV2 function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property), and then call [deleteObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property) and/or [putObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) based on requirements.

Full AWS SDK documentation for javascript can be found [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)